# Hypothesis Test of equality of two Poisson distributions using normal approximation

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

We are struggling with this question in Larson Introduction to Probability Theory and Statistical Inference.  It's question #7 in section 8.3 (Some two-sample tests).

The question boils down to the following:

You have two Poisson random variables $X$ and $Y$.  You have one observation of each, $x=47$ and $y=68$.  We're asked to test the hypothesis that $E[X]=E[Y]$ and we're told to do it by developing a test based on the approximation of a Poisson by a normal.

I see other ways to attack this problem, but not by using normal approximations. The problem is we don't have a random sample, and we have just one observation of each normal distribution.  So how can I construct a test with just that information?  All the material in the section relies on having a full random sample from each of two populations.

The answer in the back of the book says "Reject $H_0$ for any $\alpha\geq0.006$".

Any suggestions, tips, leads or answers will be greatly appreciated.  This is not homework, this came up in a group study section of bioinformaticians.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

To begin, please see [*this page*](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9561/checking-if-two-poisson-samples-have-the-same-mean) for a variety of suggestions. Googling 'test difference in Poisson rates' fetches yet additional tests--including some authoritative
ones, if you focus on notes from major universities.

An elementary method, related to testing equality of two binomial random variables and meeting the requirement to use normal approximation,
is to observe that $$Y - X \stackrel{aprx}{\sim} \mathsf{Norm}(\mu = \lambda_y - \lambda_x,\, \sigma = \sqrt{\lambda_y + \lambda_x}),$$ for $\lambda_x$ and $\lambda_y$ sufficiently large. So one can show
$$Z = \frac{Y - X}{\sqrt{Y+X}} \stackrel{aprx}{\sim} \mathsf{Norm}(0,1).$$
under $H_0: \lambda_y = \lambda_x.$

Then to test $H_0: \lambda_y = \lambda_x$ against $H_a: \lambda_y \ne \lambda_x$
at level $\alpha = .05$ one would reject for $|Z| > 1.96.$
For your data $Z \approx 1.96,$ leading to rejection with P-value
about 5%.

To verify one instance of the null distribution, a simulation of 100,000 $Z$'s with $\lambda_X = \lambda_y = 50$ gives the following histogram shown along with the standard normal density curve.

[image]

One of the tests mentioned in the link above is implemented in R statistical
software: `poisson.test(47,68)` returns P-value about 0.01.

*Note:* I can't make sense of the 'Answer' $\alpha \ge 0.006.$ My guess is that the
text may intend you to do a likelihood ratio test and that some symbol other
than $\alpha$ may have been intended.

Comment: Thank you very much for this and the pretty picture!  I mostly understand, I'm a bit shaky on how you replace $\sqrt{\lambda_x+\lambda_y}$ with $\sqrt{X+Y}$.  Are you considering $X$ as an estimate of $\lambda_x$ and $Y$ as an estimate of $\lambda_Y$?

Comment: Right to the point! The same idea as replacing $p$ by $\hat p$ in a binomial test for a single sample which has $Z = (\hat p  - p_0)/\sqrt{\hat p(1-\hat p)}.$ Or similarly, in testing $H_0: p_1 = p_2$ vs $\ne$. OK asymptotically (I guess by Slutzky's Thm), but all approximations nevertheless. To illustrate it works here  in at least one case, I did the simulation. // Hope you will look carefully at my link to stats.stackexchange.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications!  I'm just a bit concerned that when you replace $\lambda_X$ and $\lambda_Y$ with $X$ and $Y$ that the ratio $(X-Y)/\sqrt{X+Y}$ is not sufficiently approximately normal.  It's like when you replace the standard deviation with the studentized estimate of the standard deviation and what was normal now has the $T$-distribution.  Do you see what I'm worried about?

Comment: Certainly. But for what it's worth: (a) similar approximations are often used for moderate and large sample sizes, (b) for obs $\approx 50$ it seems to be OK as verified by simulation and graph. To be clear, I never claimed this is the best solution and urged your to check out others, but mine is elementary and used normal approx as specified. (And even t is 'almost normal' for sample sizes above 50.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer I don't want to sound ungrateful.  It's a good answer and helpful.  I'm just on a quest to try to find the answer that Larson had in mind.  I think the $\alpha=0.006$ thing will be a good acid test to determine whether we found his answer or not.  So please don't be offended if I don't accept your answer yet I want to wait to see if anything else is posted.  But I will give your answer an upvote, for what it's worth.  Thanks again!

Comment: For those of us who don't have Larson's book at hand, it might be helpful to know the context of the problem in the book. Just after CLT? Just after likelihood ratio tests? What other 2-sample tests nearby? // Out of context at least "Reject $H_0$ for any $\alpha\geq0.006$" makes _no_ sense. What about $\alpha = .5?$

Comment: This exercise is very late in the book, so we've already covered parameter estimation (moments, ML, Cramer-Rao, confidence intervals, two-sample procedures) and hypothesis testing (simple, composite, Neyman Pearson, two-sample tests like the t-test, paired t-test, F test, etc).  It's that section on two sample tests where this exercise lives.  The following sections go into linear modeling and non-parametric methods.